# How to combine all unique values of a dataframe column into a string

Tags: r

I have created a dataframe that looks like this

```
data <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
>data
    col1     col2    col3 
1   a1       b1      c1            
2   a1       b2      c2         
3   a1       b3      c3
```

and would like to transform into

```
    col1     col2         col3 
1   a1       b1,b2,b3     c1,c2,c3
```

It seems that `rbind` is what I am looking for. But after reading the description, I still have no clue how to implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c("a1","a1","a1"),
    col2 = c("b1","b2","b3"),
    col3 = c("c1","c2","c3"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Short version:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=",")))
```

With explanation and intermediate steps:

```
#create a custom function to list unique elements as comma separated
myfun <- function(x) {
    paste(unique(x), collapse=",")
}

#apply our function to our dataframe's columns
temp <- lapply(df, myfun)

#temp is a list, turn it into a dataframe
result <- data.frame(temp)
```

Comment: What does x mean here?

Comment: See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4fMccWy5lU) for a short intro of how to write your own functions in R

Comment: When I run the code, error says  `Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors`

Comment: If you run the "short version" line of code (and substitute your dataframe's name in for `df`), do you get the error?  Don't change any of the parts that involve `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% summarise_all(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse = ",")))
#   col1  col2     col3    
# 1 a1    b1,b2,b3 c1,c2,c3
```